# Two-way Apache Camel Routes - Infinite loop

Tags: apache, apache-camel, jms, tibco-ems, solace

I have 2 endpoints that I would like to establish routes between. Due to the nature of these endpoints (JMS topics), I would like the bridging to be bidirectional.

The underlying JmsComponent for the Tibco endpoint has the pubSubNoLocal parameter enabled which ensures that a consumer does not receive messages it has itself sent as per http://camel.apache.org/jms.html

pubSubNoLocal false
Specifies whether to inhibit the delivery of messages published by its own connection.

However this has no effect since the 2 routes create separate connections to the JMS topic my.topic.

As a result, the following will create an infinite loop. 
As mentioned, I need the routes to operate in both directions for "seamless integration"

```
<c:route>
            <c:from uri="tibco:topic:my.topic"/>
            <c:to uri="solace-jms:topic:mytopic" />
</c:route>
<c:route>
            <c:from uri="solace-jms:topic:mytopic"/>
            <c:to uri="tibco:topic:my.topic" />
</c:route>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest le consideration the concepts of [message selectors and headers](http://www.pretechsol.com/2013/11/camel-selective-consumer-using-jms_48.html#.UnUWLxAVuPA).

The way I see it, you do 2 things:

- Add a "PRODUCER" header with your Server ID (however you define it)
- All your listeners must be configured with a [negative selector](https://timjansen.github.io/jarfiller/guide/jms/selectors.xhtml) "NOT (PRODUCER='YOUR_ID')"

Done ?

(Of course, you could also use 2 topics... but I assume it is out of the question...)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add some indication in the message that it has been sent through either bridge. You could play with existing properties (redelivery ?) or better add a new one. For example set property bridged=true when it passes your bridge. Then inside your definition you can filter out each message already bridged.